# Prove for every $\alpha > 0$, the function $f'$ changes its sign in $(-\alpha, \alpha)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Consider the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})+cx, & \text{if }x \neq 0;\\
0, & \text{if }x = 0;\\
\end{cases}
$$ where $0 < c < 1$.
Prove that for every $\alpha > 0$, the derivative $f'$ changes its sign on $(-\alpha, \alpha)$.

I know $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f'(x) = 2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})+c$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f'(0)=0$. But don't know how to proceed after.

Comment: Hint: in your derivative expression, for small $x$, the first term is essentially zero, while the middle term oscillates from $-1$ to $1$ infinitely often, and of course $0<c<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any given $\alpha>0$, choose an integer $n$ so large that $$n>\frac{1}{2\pi\alpha}.$$ Define
\begin{align*}
x_1&\equiv\frac{1}{2n\pi},\\x_2&\equiv\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi}.
\end{align*}
Clearly, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both in $(0,\alpha)$. Moreover,
\begin{align*}
f'(x_1)&=2x_1\sin\left(\frac{1}{x_1}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x_1}\right)+c\\
&=\frac{1}{n\pi}\underbrace{\sin(2n\pi)}_{=0}-\underbrace{\cos(2n\pi)}_{=1}+c=c-1<0,\\
f'(x_2)&=2x_2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x_2}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x_2}\right)+c\\
&=\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}\underbrace{\sin((2n+1)\pi)}_{=0}-\underbrace{\cos((2n+1)\pi)}_{=-1}+c=c+1>0.
\end{align*}
In fact, this works as long as $-1<c<1$ (instead of $0<c<1$).